# Android onTouch called even when touch leaves View

Tags: android, graphics, touch, coordinates

Sanity check needed.

If an ACTION_DOWN occurs within a View, that View's onTouch continues to get ACTION_MOVE events even when the point of contact leaves the View (!!!).

Likewise, if the ACTION_DOWN is outside the View, we never receive anything even if that touch moves into the View's area.

This suggests that the ACTION_DOWN establishes the initial association of that touch event with a View, and that assocation never changes during the life of the View no matter where the touch coordinates may roam. I can't imagine why that would be a good idea, so I'm thinking it's an option or incomplete initialization or something.

Here's my onTouch, nothing special except that it displays the coordinates to LogCat:

```
public boolean  onTouch(View v,MotionEvent event) {

    boolean bExitValue = true;
    float   fX;
    float   fY;
    int     iAction;

    iAction = event.getActionMasked();

    if (MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE == iAction) {
        fX = event.getRawX();
        fY = event.getRawY();
        Log.d("",("X: " + fX + ", Y: " + fY));
    }

    else if (MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN != iAction) {
        bExitValue = false;
    }

    return(bExitValue);

}
```

(Yes, I know it could be more efficient without the local floats. I'm using this to experiment so it's a byproduct of other tests.)

Is this intentional behavior? Seems really odd that MotionEvents would be reported to a View that isn't even where the user is touching. This implies that your code must manually confirm that the X/Y is within your View's boundaries every time. Is that correct?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

this is how every ui toolkit works, for example take win32/linux/whatever, press your mouse on a scrollbar of your web browser, when still pressed move your mouse outside scrollbar area, you can even move your mouse outside a browser window and yet your browser scrolls its content as you move the mouse, sounds reasonable?

Comment: I see what you mean about a mouse scroll, but a mouse and a touchscreen aren't exactly the same paradigm. Given this behavior, you will very frequently need to confirm that a MotionEvent is actually within the boundaries of the View. That's possible with brute math, of course, but it's such an obvious need that there must be some OS-based way of quickly (and officially) determining it. Is there such a method/property?

Comment: whats wrong with simple checking 0 <= x < width & 0 <= y < height ?